# How can I set up socks5 proxy with authentication?

Tags: networking, proxy, socks5

I have a socks5 proxy with user password authentication. I want to set it for my full system network traffic. How can I do that? I tried proxychain, but it only works for the command line. I need to apply it for my all apps.
I'm using Ubuntu 23.10. I didn't find any place to provide my proxy authentication.

[image]

I also tried URL, but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: I have used socks 5 proxy with `ssh` port forwarding. I'm this case, ssh provides the authentication. Is that what you want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to use socks5 proxy to redirect my all incoming outgoing network request throw this proxy. like a vpn.  it can be archive via proxychain but proxychain only work in terminal. I want to do ir in my whole system .

Comment: it can be great if i can get a gui based socks5 proxy client in Linux. like proxyfire available for windows mac

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to Internet through a remote server via SSH connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053453/how-to-connect-to-internet-through-a-remote-server-via-ssh-connection)